# Dropdown menu disappears when mouse hovers

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, display

I've been struggling with this dropdown menu, when I hover the `.dropdownbtn` the dropdown menu shows but can't click on it, it disappears as I move the cursor. I'm trying to use the `display:block` and `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` method. Could anyone help me with this lines of code?

Thank you!

```
<!--Navbar : Logo + Menu-->
<nav>
  <img src="img.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownbtn"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Project1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project2</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

/* NAVBAR */
nav {
  margin: 2vh 2%;
}

img#logo {
  height: 7vh;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5vh 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--textgray);
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 12px;
    line-height: 0.6;
}

.dropdown > li {
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin: 12px auto;
}

.dropdown > li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover .dropdown {
   visibility: visible;
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its going disappearing is because you have a margin on the top of the hover box. When you hover the margin area it no longer thinks you are hovering the element. The simplest fix would be to either remove the margin on the top of your .dropdown element or adding an invisible box to bridge the gap between elements to would make it think it's still hovering the list item.

```
/* NAVBAR */
nav {
  margin: 2vh 2%;
}

img#logo {
  height: 7vh;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5vh 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px; /*updated*/
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--textgray);
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 12px;
    line-height: 0.6;
    transition: all 500ms ease;/*added*/
    opacity: 0;/*added*/
}

.dropdown > li {
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin: 12px auto;
}

.dropdown > li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
}
.dropdownbtn{/*added*/
  position: relative;
}
.dropdownbtn:hover::after{/*added*/
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-12px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdownbtn:hover .dropdown {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;/*added*/
   display: block;
}
```

You can see it working here.
https://jsfiddle.net/tmcmanus4th/shfm3zyk/

Comment: I should also note, using this method keeps the dropdown box the same size you originally had. This allows you to change the color or add a drop shadow on the dropdown without seeing an awkward gap at the top of the dropdown, should you decided to do add additional styling. I've updated the js fiddle to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
It works now and matches the design I had in mind. I wouldn't have thought about the trick with the transition property. Basically, you created an invisible animation to bind the two elements, is that correct?

And the opacity is set at first to 0 and the to 1 in the :hover selector because we want to be able to see the "effect" (a.k.a. the dropdown box) only during the hovering, right? 

I'm not sure if I'm able to understand why it is necessary to add the ::after pseudo-element, as it would work anyway.

Thanks

Comment: The opacity and transition properties combined allow for a delayed fade in/out effect which gives enough time to move the mouse to the box before it closes by 500ms (aka 0.5 seconds). But if you move your mouse very slowly to the dropdown it will still fade out before you can get to it.

The pseudo element was added to bridge the gap between the hover area and the newly visible dropdown menu as an additional failsafe. No matter how slowly the mouse moves to the dropdown, it won't fade away.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause is the `margin-top` you have on the `ul.dropdown`- it creates a gap between main menu and dropdown, and when the cursor passes across that gap going down from the main menu, the hover effect becomes inactive while the cursor isn't yet above the dropdown menu.

So add `margin-top: 0px;`, recreate the distance using `padding-top: 8px;` ( or another value you like), and also maybe add `padding-left: 0;` to not let it go to the right that far:

```css
nav {
  margin: 2vh 2%;
}

img#logo {
  height: 7vh;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5vh 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--textgray);
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 0.6;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 0;

}

.dropdown>li {
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin: 12px auto;
}

.dropdown>li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="img.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownbtn"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Project1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for helping ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that basically the dropdown li tags are far away, while you leave the parent li tag, the mouse loses the mousehover, you should delete the margins and work on the padding to increase the mousehover area until it touches, so that the pointer does not lose continuity, I'll put you like I did, but it can be improved

```
img#logo {
  height: 7vh;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5vh 0;
}
    
ul.navbar {
    padding-right: 30px;    
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--textgray);
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown > li {
    padding-left: 12px;
    margin: 12px auto;
}

.dropdown > li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover .dropdown {
   visibility: visible;
   display: block;
}
    **/*NAVBAR*/**
nav {
  margin: 2vh 2%;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems right, thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: my pleasure, wish you all the best in your website

Answer (score -1):

You have other answers here, but I have created something little differend. Take a look at it and try to understand what I have done. Here is Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kretiss/8mzk4jhp/2/.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <img src="img.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownbtn"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Project1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project2</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}

/* NAVBAR */
nav {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

img#logo {
  height: 45px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: green;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #EEE;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.dropdown a{
  line-height: 40px;
}

.dropdownbtn{
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover .dropdown {
   display: block;
}
```

From my personal scope, today, I think using flex-box is much better then using float. This code can give you a slightly different view of how to do it.

I will tell about it tommorow, now, if you want, you can look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hi, I was trying not to use flex-box, in order to understand how to achieve the dropdown menu goal without it. Anyway, thanks a lot for adding the example with the flex property. It's very useful.